# Parsing Variable Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a simple script, which I want to show me some results, but in the name of the virtual machine, I only want to the first point, everything else is left over because it generates a lot of noise.

```
$today = (get-date).Date
$backup = Get-VBRBackup | where {$_.info.jobname -eq "A. ProduccionInterna.Infraestructura Backup Copy"}
if ($backup) {
$backup.GetAllStorages() | where {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today} | select @{Name="Nombre de la VM"; Expression={$_.PartialPath[0]}}, @{Name="Size VM"; Expression={$_.Stats.BackupSize/1GB}} , @{Name="Deduplicacion"; Expression={$Session.BackupStats.DedupRatio/10}} , @{Name="Compress Ratio"; Expression={$Session.BackupStats.CompressRatio/10}} , @{Name="Fecha"; Expression={(get-date).Date}}
}
```

Result:

```
 f5downinxn.vm-37087D2020-02-21T030000_B816.vib
```

But, I wont:

```
 f5downinxn
```

The chain that entered does not seem to work.

```
[0]
```

I have also tried with

```
(".")[1]
```

EDIT

With my code:

```
Nombre de la VM : f5downinxn.vm-37087D2020-02-21T030000_B816.vib
```

With changes:

Code

```
$today = (get-date).Date
$backup = Get-VBRBackup | where {$_.info.jobname -eq "A. ProduccionInterna.Infraestructura Backup Copy"}
 if ($backup) {
$backup.GetAllStorages() | where {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today} | select @{Name="Nombre de la VM"; Expression={$_.PartialPath[0].split('.')[0]}}, @{Name="Size VM"; Expression={$_.Stats.BackupSize/1GB}} , @{Name="Deduplicacion"; Expression={$Session.BackupStats.DedupRatio/10}} , @{Name="Compress Ratio"; Expression={$Session.BackupStats.CompressRatio/10}} , @{Name="Fecha"; Expression={(get-date).Date}} 
}


Nombre de la VM :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.PartialPath` property is a `Veeam.Backup.Common.CPartialPath` object. The tabular output is performing some string conversion magic, but the underlying object is ***not a string***. However, `Veeam.Backup.Common.CPartialPath` has a `ToString()` override method that should make this task easier.

```
Select @{Name="Nombre de la VM"; Expression={$_.PartialPath.ToString().Split('.')[0]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for the explanation, since it has helped me understand how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your `Select-Object` where you're currently returning just `$_.PartialPath` as the VM name:

```
$_.PartialPath.Split('.')[0]
```

This should split the contents of the `PartialPath` property on the `.` character into an array of strings and then return you the first one.

Note that you may get errors if `PartialPath` ever contains a string without a `.` as the split would then not generate an array and the use of `[0]` would be invalid.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the change you've made.

Comment: OK, i did changes

Comment: I wanted to see your updated script actually. But perhaps we wrongly assumed you'd added the `[0]` to this and it wasn't working `$_.PartialPath[0]`. In which case try this `$_.PartialPath[0].split('.')[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit confused as to what you are executing when you actually get the name of the VM returned. Is it the code you put at the top of your question or not?

Comment: That is, first I show how the name shows me with the code of my question, and then I show what it shows when I modify my code with your help.

Comment: `$_.PartialPath[0].split('.')[0]` should be working then.